# How does css loader interprets the @import and url() in css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, css-loader, webpack-loader

How does the `css-loader` interprets the @import or url() in css

For exmaple if in (index.js) module if i import (Style.css)

```
import './Style.css';

function Component(){
   //javascript code
}
```

My (Style.css) file if I have

```
body{
  background:url('./image.png')
}
```

So, when webpack see's that `import` of `Style.css` in `index.js` module, How does `css-loader` inteprets that `url()` syntax of background property. will the `url('./image.png')` be converted to `require('./image.png)`.

For example will

```
body{
  background:url('./image.png')
}
```

converted to

```
body{
  background:require('./image.png')  //not a valid css syntax
}
```

Because in the documentation there is resolution example like:

> url('./image.png') => require('./image.png')

So, I want to know does the whole `url('./image.png')` syntax is replaced by `require('./image.png')`. if it is the case than `background` with `require()` is not a valid `css` syntax.

Does interpreting `url()` as `require()` means converting it to `require()` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not that simple as replacing `url(<>)` with `require(<>)` in content.

`css-loader` first loads necessary plugins including [url-parser](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/0902353c328d4d18e8ed2755fe9c83c03c53df81/src/plugins/postcss-url-parser.js)

`url-parser` then [collects all `url(<>)` occurences and generates some metadata about them](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/0902353c328d4d18e8ed2755fe9c83c03c53df81/src/plugins/postcss-url-parser.js#L109)

Later on when the loader javascript code is generated [it wraps those things in `___CSS_LOADER_GET_URL_IMPORT___` function](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/0902353c328d4d18e8ed2755fe9c83c03c53df81/src/utils.js#L274)

Comment: I want to know will url() in css be replaced by require() which is not a valid css property. then how it will work